# ECDSA Signature - extract R|S from ASN 1. format

Tags: cryptography, ethereum, bitcoin, ecdsa

I am trying to exact the r, s and v from a ECDSA in ASN 1. format.

With these three parameters I'm planning on calculating the Public Key out of the Signature.

My Signature is 73 Bytes long. How can I extract the r,s and the ? Which bytes are the Prefix?

This is my Signature:

```
304502204C3AB9B1860008F0727D4208D55D21778D765A2F7DD005409F6DA6D088DDBD0A02210097FED70019662BAD8196480DD0D9DBDFD96137D19E31BA933E80F1A12BBFF41D
```

So far I read that the first two Bytes `30`, `45` are the Prefix - which leaves me still with 71 Bytes

Comment: Any introduction on ASN.1 will explain the SEQUENCE and INTEGER types, which are the only two types represented by that signature. [Here](http://luca.ntop.org/Teaching/Appunti/asn1.html) is an old one that nevertheless contains everything you need.

Comment: Note that stackoverflow is for specific programming questions only. There are also the bitcoin and cryptography sites.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about cryptography without involving programming (yet)

Answer (score 1):

You can use any ASN.1 parser you get your hands on or write one for yourself. A simple Ruby snippet does the job quite nicely:

```
require 'openssl'
der = "304502204C3AB9B1860008F0727D4208D55D21778D765A2F7DD005409F6DA6D088DDBD0A02210097FED70019662BAD8196480DD0D9DBDFD96137D19E31BA933E80F1A12BBFF41D".scan(/../).map { |x| x.hex.chr }.join
asn1 = OpenSSL::ASN1.decode(der)
r,s = asn1.value
puts "r: #{r.value}\ns: #{s.value}"
```

This outputs:

```
r: 34479535231181969595855089292034272330749384807106277743970674769427519356170
s: 68749503168666332080677992907050713241533227486157775318500627956188309353501
```

Answer (score 0):

The following OpenSSL command to be executed on a bash or compatible shell does also the job. This would not require an additional interpreter. `sig.bin` is containing the signature in DER format. Adjust to your needs, e.g. `echo ... | xxd -r -ps > sig.bin` could convert hex to binary.

```bash
r=$(openssl asn1parse -in sig.bin -inform DER | sed -n 2p | sed -n 's/.*INTEGER.*:\(.*\)/\1/p')
s=$(openssl asn1parse -in sig.bin -inform DER | sed -n 3p | sed -n 's/.*INTEGER.*:\(.*\)/\1/p')
echo $r$s
```